# How to include the heading pattern when creating multiple text files from a single text file

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have this text file named **data.txt**

```
W1M0130
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_002 15 14 149 64 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_003 4 3 233 100 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_005 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_007 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$END
W1M0200
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_002 12 11 136 58 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_003 3 2 213 91 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_005 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_007 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:30 SS_008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$END
W1M0230
...
```

And here is my code on how I split this single text file into multiple text files:

```
textFile = "C:\data.txt"
saveTo = "C:\"
writeTo = ""
headingPattern = "(W[0-9][A-Z][0-9]*)"

dim fso,fileFrom,regex
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set fileFrom = fso.OpenTextFile(textFile)
set regex = new RegExp

with regex
  .Pattern = headingPattern
  .IgnoreCase = false
  .Global = True
end with

while fileFrom.AtEndOfStream <> true
  line = fileFrom.ReadLine
  set matches = regex.Execute(line)

  if matches.Count > 0 then
    writeTo = saveTo & matches(0).SubMatches(0) & ".txt"
    set fileTo = fso.CreateTextFile(writeTo)
  else
    fileTo.WriteLine(line)
  end if
wend

set fileFrom = nothing
set fso = nothing
set regex = nothing
```

One of the output is **W1M0130.txt** and this is the output text file:

```
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_002 15 14 149 64 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_003 4 3 233 100 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_005 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_007 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$END
```

I manage to split the single text file into multiple text files but I am having a problem on how to include the heading pattern line which is (in the example) **W1M0130**.

Expected result should be:

```
W1M0130
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_002 15 14 149 64 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_003 4 3 233 100 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_005 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_007 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$END
```

I already search the internet for hours and tried some *trial and error* ways but still didn't get the expected result. Your help is very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `fileTo.WriteLine(matches(0).SubMatches(0))` to the if like this :

```
 if matches.Count > 0 then
    writeTo = saveTo & matches(0).SubMatches(0) & ".txt"
    set fileTo = fso.CreateTextFile(writeTo)
    fileTo.WriteLine(matches(0).SubMatches(0))
 else
    fileTo.WriteLine(line)
 end if
```

Your output will be : [notepad W1M0130.txt]

```
W1M0130
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_001 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_002 15 14 149 64 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_003 4 3 233 100 0 0 0 1
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_004 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_005 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_006 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_007 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
03/12/2012 00:00 SS_008 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
$END
```

Comment: Good to know it helped :)